# Generate unique integral type id for each type that is consistent between compilations

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am working on a library that, among other things, allows the serialization of PODs into a file to be loaded later and I need a way to preserve the type. The way i handle this now is via a template function that simply returns its address casted to an int. This works fine as long as I only run the same executable. If I change something and compile, it doesn't return the same number anymore. Probably because the linker placed those functions somewhere else which results in a different address being returned.

```
using namespace std;

struct pod1{int a;};
struct pod2{int a;};
struct pod3{int a;};
template <typename T>
uintptr_t getTypeId(){

    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&getTypeId<T>);
}


int main(){

    cout << getTypeId<pod1>() << ", " << getTypeId<pod2>();
    return 0;
}
// output 4206048, 4206064
```

in a different compilation adding only a third pod
    using namespace std;

```
struct pod1{int a;};
struct pod2{int a;};
struct pod3{int a;};
template <typename T>
uintptr_t getTypeId(){

    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&getTypeId<T>);
}


int main(){

    cout << getTypeId<pod1>() << ", " << getTypeId<pod2>() << ", " << getTypeId<pod3>();
    return 0;
}
// output 4206080, 4206096, 4206112
```

Obviously, adding the third pod and instantiating the template with it gives different type ids for the other two.
I know this is a long shot in C++ but is there a way to generate the same id's for each type even if code changes?

Comment: If you don't need cross-compiler compatibility, you could probably craft something based on `std::type_info::name`.

Comment: Since it's your library, couldn't you include type ID constants as static functions of the types themselves?  That also allows for versioning if you are ever forced to revise a type, though for that you might be better making separate new typev2 v3...  for revised objects.  On second thought that might require inheriting from some CObject class if  you want to be able to access it without type-specific code, which causes its own pain.

Comment: It's my library, am just one of the people working on it. It's actually an old library that I'm trying to wrap in a new interface that satisfies certain criteria, type checking for PODs is one of them. The idea is that users can serialize and store any POD and retrieve it. So the interface itself ia a template that can take any POD, store it, and then the user calls something like `getPod<podtype>(name)` and the interface is supposed to check the type and throw if there is a mismatch

Comment: Is it a requirement for everyone never to modify the fields of an existing type?  Otherwise you can have a file that is (typename) (typedata) where (typedata) no longer matches the current definition of the type.

Comment: The fields are not being changed. Its the action of adding new pods and trying to use the library to load data serialized to a file into one of the old pods that doesn't work. please check edit.